# queue.front() in C++ returns a strange value

Tags: c++, queue

I'm coding in C++ and making use of the  library.
My code goes something like this:

```cpp
struct request {
    int order;
    float size;
};
typedef struct request req;
.. ...
std::queue <req> wait_queue;
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    req r;
    r.order = i + 1;
    r.size = 100;
    wait_queue.push(r);
}
// ...
if (!wait_queue.empty()) {
    req r = wait_queue.front();
    // do something...
}
```

Where the `req r` do not conflict because they're defined in different functions in actuality.
Now I know the variables are saved correctly because when I run `gdb` and type `p wait_queue` it shows:

```
(gdb) $1 = std::queue wrapping: std::deque with 5 elements = {{order = 1, size = 100}, {order = 2, size = 100}, {order = 3, 
    size = 100}, {order = 4, size = 100}, {order = 5, size = 100}}
```

But after `r = wait_queue.front()`, `p r` shows:

```
(gdb) $2 = {order = 6417952, size = 0}
```

So I want to know how this can happen, and what I can do to make sure `r` will hold `{order = 1, size = 100}`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the contents of wait_queue just before you accessed the front?

Comment: @SolidMercury Yup.. The 'p r' is checked right after 'p wait_queue'

Comment: `wait_queue.push();` compiles?

Comment: Use `wait_queue.push(r)`?

Comment: @Ame Sorry, that's a typo. I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the given code, so i'll suspect it's coming from the lines before `if (!wait_queue.empty()) {`

Comment: @Ame I guess so... But the actual code consists of various functions from different source files so it's kind of hard to post here. But whatever caused the problem, don't you think the two lines of gdb seem weird?

Comment: @정진하 There is nothing wrong in your code. It must be definitely a corruption happening in the code which you have not posted. Only if you post the complete code, someone can help you. Otherwise you should use debugger to identify the source of corruption. To identify the that,  you can use "memory breakpoint" or "memory watch point".